# из десятичной в двоичную

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

В функцию передаю массив:

```
char *buffer
```

в нём хранятся числа в десятичной записи. Нужно перевести их в `int`. Числа внутри - от 0 до 255. 
Первый вопрос: как перевести каждый элемент данного массива в число в десятичной СИ? 
Второй вопрос: есть функция для перевода из 10-ой СИ в двоичную:

```
    void getBin(int num, char *str, int *cnt)
    {
         int mask = 0x10 << 1;
         *(str + 8) = '\0';
         while (mask >>= 1)
         {
              *str++ = !!(mask & num) + '0';
              *(cnt)++;
         }
    }
```

Вызываю данную функцию так:

```
getBin(number, buf. &counter);
```

где `number` - число в десятичной записи (`int`);
     `buf` - указатель `char`, в который будет записан результат;
     `counter` - `int`-вая переменная, которая мне нужна для подсчёта итераций  в функции.

Почему-то после вызова в `counter` 0 хранится, да и в `buf` не то, что мне нужно..Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: У вас явно какая-то терминологическая путаница...

Comment: Подскажите, в чём?

Comment: Например, что значит, что в buffer хранятся числа в десятичной записи? Это значит 1) что каждый char рассматривается как число, 2) что там записано одно число в виде строки, 3) что там записано несколько чисел в виде строки? На 1 наталкивает то, что чисел много и они от 1 до 255. На 2 или 3 - что они в *десятичной* записи - ну какая может быть запись у бинарного представления в памяти? И так почти везде...

Comment: Дайте несколько примеров входных и выходных данных

Comment: 1. Поясню конкретнее: я считал файл в виде массива байт в `char *`. Теперь в каждой ячейке памяти там хранятся числа от 0 до 255. Насчёт примера входных данных  - я пытался к элементам массива обращаться как `buffer[i] - '0'`, чтобы их в `int` числа перевести, но не помогло. Поэтому я думаю, как корректнее это сделать.

Comment: Есть старая функция radix

Comment: она разве есть в ANSI?

Comment: В общем, первый вопрос я решил: оказалось надо просто сделать явное приведение типов (дописать `int`).

Answer (score 0):

Я напишу работающий код, и выскажу своё мнение.

Первое, мне совсем не понятно, зачем писать вот так :

```
*str++ = !!(mask & num) + '0';
*(cnt)++;
```

Т.е. здесь сложная структура кода, так он еще и вдобавок не работает. И Вы не пришли к мысли попробовать упростить и написать линейно, без кучи операций в 1 строчке. А обратились за помощью сюда. Мне это просто крайне непонятно, почему так критично сохранить именно такую структуру кода, и почему ВЫ уверенны, что сами не запутались в нём. А Вы запутались и ошиблись.

Итак, отвечая на вопрос:

Первая ошибка в строке `*(cnt)++;`. Заменяем на `*cnt += 1;` и всё начинает считать. Опять же, как вариант, просто `(*cnt)++;`. Смысл не меняется.

Вторая ошибка в строке `int mask = 0x10 << 1;`. Меняем на `int mask = 1 << 8;` и всё становиться правильно. Так же если автору принципиально, то `int mask = 0x10 << 3;` Заходим в любой калькулятор, с возможность операции левого сдвига, и 16 разрядной системой и всё становиться очевидным.